# Python melt dataframe based on values of comma-separated character vector column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm currently working on a test where I have different regions with some associated statistic, and a comma-separated list of genes that lie in those regions. This list will be variable in number, and may not contain anything (`"NA"`).

How can I "melt" this dataframe:

```
 region_id  statistic      genelist
          1        2.5       A, B, C
          2        0.5    B, C, D, E
          3        3.2          <NA>
          4        0.1          E, F
```

Into something like this:

```
     region_id  statistic gene
           1       2.5    A
           1       2.5    B
           1       2.5    C
           2       0.5    B
           2       0.5    C
           2       0.5    D
           2       0.5    E
           3       3.2 <NA>
           4       0.1    E
           4       0.1    F
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use:

```
# Splitting on , and joining with region_id and statistic columns
val = pd.concat([df.region_id, 
                 df.statistic, 
                 df.genelist.str.split(',', expand=True)], 
                axis=1)

# Unpivoting and ignoring variable column
m = pd.melt(val, id_vars=['region_id', 'statistic'])\
            .loc[:, ['region_id', 'statistic', 'value']]

# Ignoring Null values and sorting based on region_id
m[m.value.notnull()]\
.sort_values('region_id')\
.reset_index(drop=True)\
.rename(columns={'value':'gene'})

 region_id  statistic gene
       1       2.5    A
       1       2.5    B
       1       2.5    C
       2       0.5    B
       2       0.5    C
       2       0.5    D
       2       0.5    E
       3       3.2 <NA>
       4       0.1    E
       4       0.1    F
```

Answer (score 7):

Use the below code, use `stack` to stack it, after that split on `', '`, then stack it again, since we stacked it twice, use `unstack` to unstack with `-2`, then reset the index using `reset_index` with `-1`, after that do the final `reset_index` with no parameters:

```
print(df.set_index(['region_id', 'statistic'])
   .stack()
   .str.split(', ', expand=True)
   .stack()
   .unstack(-2)
   .reset_index(-1, drop=True)
   .reset_index()
)
```

Comment: It will great, if you provide explanation of your code approach.

Comment: @shaikmoeed Edited mine

Answer (score 4):

using [stack](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html)

```
df=df.join(df.pop('genelist').str.split(',',expand=True))
df.set_index(['region_id','statistic']).stack().reset_index(level=[0,1],name='gene')
```

using [melt](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.melt.html)

```
df=df.join(df.pop('genelist').str.split(',',expand=True))
pd.melt(df,id_vars=['region_id','statistic'],value_name='gene').dropna()
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `df.assign` and `explode` to do it. Explode is used to break columns data into multiple rows given that the data is in a list format.
Each data in genelist can be converted to a list, separating it using a comma and then use explode on the genelist column.

```
(df.assign(genelist=df.genelist.str.split(',')).explode('genelist'))
```