# python pandas melt column by substring

Tags: python, pandas, data-science, melt

I have dataframe:

```
         subject           A_target_word_gd  A_target_word_fd B_target_word_gd  B_target_word_fd  subject_type 
           1                      1             2                3                    4             mild 
           2                      11            12               13                   14             moderate
```

And I want to melt it to a dataframe that will look:

```
     cond    subject    subject_type     value_type   value
      A         1        mild             gd           1           
      A         1        mild             fg           2           
      B         1        mild             gd           3            
      B         1        mild             fg           4  
      A         2        moderate         gd           11           
      A         2        moderate         fg           12           
      B         2        moderate         gd           13            
      B         2        moderate         fg           14          
...

...
```

Meaning, to melt based on the delimiter.

What is the best way to do that?

Comment: `df[['cond','level','word','value_type']] = df['cond'].str.split('_',expand=True)` ? then you can drop the `word` column

Comment: I do not see any application of melt here. You can just generate new columns in different ways. `df['cond_new'] = df['cond'].apply(lambda x: x.split()[0]  if x is not None else x)` and do the same to get the other column or can follow anky_91

Comment: @DataPsycho I'm sorry I was confused and didn't write the original df good, please see my edit

Comment: Does this answer your question? [melt column by substring of the columns name in pandas (python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59550804/melt-column-by-substring-of-the-columns-name-in-pandas-python)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `str.split()` to melt on the delimiter, this is explained in [melt data frame and split values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13808553/melt-data-frame-and-split-values) for `R` and in [Python melt dataframe based on values of comma-separated character vector column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55016520/python-melt-dataframe-based-on-values-of-comma-separated-character-vector-column) and [Python melt dataframe based on values of comma-separated character vector column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55016520/python-melt-dataframe-based-on-values-of-comma-separated-character-vector-column) for python